# GatsbyJS: component in createPage template

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using createPages API in Gatsby in order to create pages. I got a template for all of the pages:

```
const pageTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/page/WpPage.js`)
```

However, I am not really sure how to use a component in template file. Something like:

```
import { Herotext } from "./hero/herotext"

const WpPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { wpPage } = data
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
            <h1><Herotext /></h1>
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: wpPage.content }} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

As seen above I have created herotext.js which should store the title and some other text. My herotext contains:

```
import React from "react"

export const Herotext = ({ data }) => {
  return <h2>[data.wpPage.ACFundersider.hero.heroHeading}</h2>
}

export const query = graphql`
  query HeroById($id: String) {
    wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
      ACFundersider {
        hero {
          heroText
          heroHeading
        }
      }
      id
    }
  }
`
```

The GraphQL query works when I test in graphiql IDE, but it returns error on frontend:

```
here was a problem parsing "C:/Users/mig/Desktop/Gatsby/mf20/src/templates/page/hero/herotext.js"; any GraphQL
fragments or queries in this file were not processed.

This may indicate a syntax error in the code, or it may be a file type
that Gatsby does not know how to parse.

File: C:/Users/mig/Desktop/Gatsby/mf20/src/templates/page/hero/herotext.js

./src/templates/page/hero/herotext.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\mig\Desktop\Gatsby\mf20\src\templates\page\hero\herotext.js
  5:53  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

Not really sure how to create my herotext.js so it will be used when creating all of the pages with createPage API. I have tried changing my query in all sorts of way but no luck.

When I do console.log(data) in herotext.js I get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby gives you a lot of flexibility to use the template system and the context API. However, the "standard" approach is to use the `gatsby-node.js` to create dynamic pages, pointing to some template, send some unique value to the template and use it to filter a GraphQL query to fetch the needed data. For example, extracted from [Gatsby's tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-seven/):

```
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        // Data passed to context is available
        // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
```

Here you are looping through some array of pages (`result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.node`) to create dynamic pages using the `slug` as a path value, then, it sends the `slug` as a unique value to the template (`blog-post.js`).

In your case, I would suggest a folder structure like `/templates/WpPage.js` (removing the `/page`) to avoid potential nesting issues.

Your `WpPage`, should receive some unique value to filter (it seems to be the `id`). This is your entry point for your data and from there, you can send it to any desired component:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default function SomeTemplate({ data }) {
  conosle.log("your data is in", data);

  return (
      <Layout>
            <Herotext heroText={data.wpPage.ACFundersider.heroText} />
      </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query HeroById($id: String) {
    wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
      ACFundersider {
        hero {
          heroText
          heroHeading
        }
      }
      id
    }
  }
`
```

*Note: I removed the `<h1>` since you were wrapping an `<h2>` inside an `<h1>`.*

At this point, your GraphQL query is getting the `id` (sent via context) and it's being used to filter through `wpPage` node. In the template query, your data is stored inside `props.data` (destructured as `data` in this case). From here, you can send a `props` called `heroText` to your `HeroText` component with the need data and your component will be responsible to print it as you wish:

```
export const Herotext = ({ heroText }) => {
  return <h2>{heroText}</h2>
}
```

The main idea to use the template as an entry point of your data. From there, you can distribute and structure the components and data as you wish.